# Difference between cross apply and inner join based on below example

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below  I have Two tables #temp and #temp2.

```
 create table #temp
    (
     col1 int
     )

     insert into #temp values(6),(1),(2),(3),(null)



     create table #temp2
     (
       col1 int
       )
       insert into #temp2 values(1),(2),(1),(2),(3),(null)
```

And also i have two queries below
With INNER JOIN:

```
 SELECT t1.col1,
           Sum(t2.col1) AS col1
    FROM   #temp t1
           INNER JOIN #temp2 t2
                   ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
    GROUP  BY t1.col1
```

Result:

```
col1    col1
1        2
2        4
3        3
```

And second query is

With CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #temp t1
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(col1) AS col1
                    FROM   #temp2 t2
                    WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1) A
```

Result:

```
col1    col1
1        2
2        4
3        3
6       NULL
```

Now, I want to know the difference between CROSS APPLY and INNER JOIN. I Know CROSS APPLY similar like INNER JOIN For each and Every record of #temp(first table) cross apply will execute.But I am getting Different Result Set based on above result sets  Can any one Please Explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those rows for which there are no corresponding matches in right table expression, will refer NULL values in columns of right table expression. The CROSS APPLY is semantically equivalent to INNER JOIN (or to be more precise its like a CROSS JOIN with a correlated sub-query)  with a implicit join condition of 1=1.

Comment: please see this : http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/

Comment: CROSS APPLY was designed to give you a "join" option for table-valued functions.  When you are working with two tables/views, it would be more appropriate to use JOINs and save the [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) keyword for table-valued functions.  This will promote clarity and maintainability for future enhancements or bug fixes.

Comment: @DeadZone Can you Please Explain Why 6 came in col1 in CROSS APPLY Query Result set?

Comment: This is indeed a very curious case. That fourth column should have shown up if you used an `OUTER APPLY`, but not a `CROSS APPLY`. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that you are using an aggregate function? Does it still show up if you replace `Sum(col1)` with just `col1`?

Comment: Yes,But if you replaced with col1 instead of sum(col1) will get result like inner join only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If my understanding of cross apply is correct the reason you are getting different results here is that CROSS APPLY will apply whatever comes after apply (the right operator) to every row in the left operator (#temp).  This means that the number of rows in the result will be the same as the number of rows in #temp.  Basing my answer off of  "The table-valued function acts as the right input and the outer table expression acts as the left input. The right input is evaluated for each row from the left input and the rows produced are combined for the final output." from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx.

Note that if you really wanted the results to be the same you could change your cross apply query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #temp t1
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(col1) AS col1
                    FROM   #temp2 t2
                    WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1) A
WHERE A.col1 IS NOT NULL
```

Also, note that INNER JOIN is defined to be where there is a match on both sides.  In your case this means that there were only 3 rows.  If you had used a LEFT OUTER join instead you would have gotten the same results in this case as the CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Thank you. I Understood the behavior of Cross Apply when Handling with Nulls by your Explanation